# Unit test Error - ConfigService of ngx-config

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have just started writing unit test cases for Angular 4 application. So this might be very easy.

We are using ConfigService of [@ngx-config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-config). and we have written ConfigurationService like below.

ConfigurationService.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class ConfigurationService{
    constructor(private configService: ConfigService){}

    public get urls(): Urls {
       return (this.configService.getSettings() as IConfiguration).urls;
    }
}

// configuration.ts
export interface Urls {
   user: string;
   application: string;
}
export interface IConfiguration{
  urls: Urls;
}
```

Now inside component we are using this service to get urls which we have defined in config.dev.json.

inside user.component.ts

```
   import {ConfigService} from "@ngx-config/core";
   
   config: ConfigurationService;

   constructor(private cs: ConfigService){
      this.config = new ConfigurationService(cs);
   }

   ngOnInit(){
     const userUrls: Urls = this.config.urls.user;
   }
```

now in my user.component.spec.ts

```
describe('UserComponent', () => {
   beforeEach(async(() => {
       TestBed.configureTestingModule({
         imports: [
            // all other imports
            ConfigModule.forRoot()
         ]
       }).compileComponents();
   }));

   beforeEach(() => {
     fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UserComponent);
     component = fixture.componentInstance;
     fixture.detectChanges();
     component.ngOnInit();
   });

   it('should create', () => {
     expect(component).toBeTruthy();
   });
});
```

This will throw error.

> TypeError: Cannot read property of 'urls' of undefined.

TIA.